# ListBox unselect items

Tags: vb.net

Want to unselect items on condition. I noticed that when do setselected then i get error on enxt loop because index was changed after first loop, therefore i decided to refresh and make everytime loop again but after one item is unselected i have invinitive loop for second one. How to accomplish that properly? Listbox is binded to datasource.

```
sss:
        For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count - 1
            Dim variationswert1 As DataRowView = ListBox1.SelectedItems(i)
            Dim name As String = ListBox1.GetItemText(variationswert1)
if name = "TR8" Then 
            ListBox1.SetSelected(i, False)
            ListBox1.Refresh()
            GoTo sss
End If
        Next
```

**EDIT: (for further discussion):**

```
 For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
                If ListBox1.SelectedItems.Contains(ListBox1.Items(i))  Then

      MsgBox(ListBox1.GetItemText(ListBox1.Items(i)))
                MsgBox(ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString)    

                    ListBox1.SetSelected(i, False)
                End If
            Next
            ListBox1.Refresh()
```

Comment: First of all, don't use `labels` and `goto`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are iterating through the Selected Items, but since you are going to change that array, any loop you will run will eventually fail :

- `For Each` will fail because you will modify the collection
- `For i = 0 to ...` will fail because you will remove an item and therfore end in an `OutOfRangeException` (or something like that)

The idea would be to :

- Run through all your items :

  - If the item is selected and the item text is `"TR8"`, unselect this item

And here would be the code :

```
Dim FoundItem As Object 'Or Whatever class the items are

For i = 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    If ListBox1.SelectedItems.Contains(ListBox1.Items(i)) AndAlso _ 
       ListBox1.GetItemText(ListBox1.Item(i)) = "TR8"  Then
        FoundItem = ListBox1.Items(i)
        ListBox1.SetSelected(i, False)
        MsgBox(FoundItem.ToString())
    End If
Next
ListBox1.Refresh()
```

Comment: this is great hoever have one more thing. What if i want to read values of selected record before it will be unselected - take a look on my main post in edit section i used this query with my modification but it failes. How to correct that?

Comment: @JimmyJimm Concerning your edit, that is because the `i` variable is used to run through the `Items` collection, not the `SelectedItems`. See my updated post.

Comment: can you check my main post (edit) again - that seems to be working, what do you think?

Comment: no, something is wrong unfortunetly for some loops where is gaps between selected items, this value stays and is not changing...

Comment: somehow as i notice its loosing the value

Comment: is there any other way instead of ListBox1.SelectedValue?

Comment: Well the problem with SelectedValue is that you can only get one even if many are selected. What do you want to achieve exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Is looping all thi items, not onlys the selected, viable?

```
sss:
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

    If ListBox1.SelectedItems.Contains(ListBox1.Items(i)) Then 
        Continue For
    End If

    Dim variationswert1 As DataRowView = ListBox1.Items(i)
    Dim name As String = ListBox1.GetItemText(variationswert1)
    if name = "TR8" Then 
        ListBox1.SetSelected(i, False)
        ListBox1.Refresh()
        GoTo sss
    End If
Next
```

**EDIT:**

Using for each and leaving the rest the same:

```
For Each item In ListBox1.Items

    If Not ListBox1.SelectedItems.Contains(item) Then
        Continue For
    End If

    Dim variationswert1 As DataRowView = item
    Dim name As String = ListBox1.GetItemText(variationswert1)
    If name = "TR8" Then

        ListBox1.SetSelected(ListBox1.Items.IndexOf(item), False)
        ListBox1.Refresh()
        GoTo sss
    End If
Next
```

Simplifing it, I may have not understood it, but it seems that you want to unslect all the listbox items that their text is "TR8"

```
For Each item In ListBox1.Items
    If ListBox1.SelectedItems.Contains(item) And ListBox1.GetItemText(item) = "TR8" Then
        ListBox1.SetSelected(ListBox1.Items.IndexOf(item), False)
        ListBox1.Refresh()

    End If
Next
```

**EDIT 2:**

So without for each and

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
If ListBox1.SelectedItems.Contains(ListBox.Items(i)) And ListBox1.GetItemText(ListBox.Items(i)) = "TR8" Then
    ListBox1.SetSelected(i, False)
    ListBox1.Refresh()

End If
```

Next

Comment: What does not work? I think i corrected it, I was using selectedItems for `variationswet1`. And isn't it simple to use a for each? Or do you need the `i` for something else than getting the index?

Comment: your solution giving invinitive loop. i dont need this id you can present solution with for each ( i paste also for each approach that can be used)

Comment: Edited my answer for the for each. Also the `GoTo sss` seems to be just making it longer, every time i unselect one it starts from the beggining again. Is that what you intended?

Comment: for second code i get: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll because the list was modified

Comment: ahh i know why we cannot change in for each otherwise we get exactly that error, we have to use based on my (or yours) first snippet of code

Comment: Are you modifing the Items of the listbox somewhere else? I can run both of them withou exception showing up. Where does it launch it? At the first or any other iteration?

Comment: after first because for each was modified - note that i have bounded listbox to datasource. We have to play with not for each solution and for your first one i get infinitive loop

Comment: Try that last one, i hope it works. I just saw that the first one, the first if needed to be negated... My bad, too early in the morning

Comment: will check it as soon as poosible and come back here again @Aimnox